# How to get repository setting values in GitHub using GitHub API?

Tags: github, github-api

I would like to get repository setting values such as "Require pull request review before merging" and "Require status check to pass before merging". Can we get these values using GitHub API? or is there any other ways we can get those value? TIA

Answer (score 0):

In the REST API, this information is available under Branches / [Protected branches](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/branches/branch-protection).

For example, using the GitHub CLI, for a repo with a branch `main`, we can get its branch protection settings with

```bash
gh api repos/{owner}/{repo}/branches/main/protection
```